# Changing the hostname in systemFile doesnt reflect in next js

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, localhost

System : windows 11
Next version : 13.5.0

Problem Statement
I want my local development to run on http://localhost.example.com:3000 instead of http://localhost:3000

I changed my Windows\System32\hosts\drivers\etc- hosts file

[image]

When i run npm run dev in terminal
My local is running on http://localhost:3000
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix
npm run dev -- -H localhost.example.com

It forces  it to run on this
[image]

Reason: By default, Next.js uses localhost as the hostname. If you want to change this, you can specify a custom hostname using the --hostname flag when running the development server.